# laravel/codeception : test if json response contains only certain keys

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, codeception

I have a json array coming from my api as response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "abc"
    }
}
```

I am using `laravel` for api and `laravel-codeception` for testing.

```
public function getAll(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->sendGET($this->endpoint);
    }
```

I have to test if the response contains only `id` and `name` key (not any other key) example this response should fail the test.

```
{
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "abc",
          "email":"abc@xyz"
        }
    }
```

I have found `$I->seeResponseContainsJson()`, but it checks if JSON is present or not. It does not check if JSON response contains only specified keys.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) from the `data`, remove the `id` and the `name` and check for the length? I don't exactly know where you are putting this script, so I'm not entirely sure that this is possible.

Comment: It would work as a custom helper method: http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Helpers